# How Can I Expose the EmailAddress Attribute on the Principal Context during Development

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm trying to retrieve users assigned to a specific AD group. During development there are a number of attributes that are not available, but are available at runtime. An example of this is the EmailAddress.

Here is my code:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, theDomain);
GroupPrincipal group = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, theGroup);
PrincipalSearchResult <Principal> members = group.GetMembers();
foreach (Principal value in members)
{
     if (value.StructuralObjectClass == "user")
     {
         if (value.EmailAddress == "john.smith@aol.com")
         {

         }
     }  
}
```

EmailAddress is not available and can't be checked, BUT if I inspect the "value" object at runtime it is there.

How do I change the above code to expose the EmailAddress attribute as well as the other attributes that are not exposed whe using the GroupPrincipal?

Comment: What do you mean by "EmailAddress is not available and can't be checked"? How are you trying to check it?